# EXCEL - Function Lookup - confusing behaviour

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

See simple lookup example below, as taken from the MS official website]

```
=LOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$A$6,$B$2:$B$6)
```

Changes in the 'lookup-vector' result in wrong outcomes of the lookup function:

[image: See animated gif]

Any ideas why this happens?

[FYI: I am only allowed to post one link]

Answer (score 1):

Your issue arises because to use `LOOKUP` in *array form* your data must be sorted.

When you put 100 before the 6 your data becomes *unsorted* and you'll get unexpected errors.

The strongly recommended practice for *array form* lookups is to use `VLOOKUP` or `HLOOKUP`. The following formula will work even when you change your frequency column:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$B$6,2,0)
```

Source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOOKUP-function-446D94AF-663B-451D-8251-369D5E3864CB

Comment: Thanks a lot - appreciate it!