# VLOOKUP in Excel does not work for me (text and numbers)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem similar to [EXCEL - Function Lookup - confusing behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717097/excel-function-lookup-confusing-behaviour), but the solution does not work for me. I have a table with some text and numbers and it works in an extraordinary way:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Even if I sort the first column does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So try:

```
vlookup(H3;F3:G11;2;0)
```

My system uses the "," as its separator so this is also correct:

```
   vlookup(H3,F3:G11,2,0)
```

As it matches the working example I show in the image.

But you might want to add iferror().

If you check excel help, it will show you examples of the indexing column being the left-most column in the data array (F3:G11) then you can call the result from any column, either column 1, or in this case column 2.

Also,m it helps if you provide data that we can copy to test with - so we don't have to type what you show.

[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks - here is the live link https://vscht-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/kohoutj_vscht_cz/ERsVc8bGbRBBi8bJXDPfEdoBCceDmt5f6JdrvYI_HbDXYw?e=bhleR1 with data

Comment: Why it is now working what I tried? :-D Solution: =VLOOKUP(H3;F$3:G$11;2;0) works for me, thanks! But I don't understand why the original syntax (valid according help too) does not work.

Comment: @HonzaK. if you look, you split the data array into two parts. That is not a recognizable form for vlookup.